# Prove using induction that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $f(n) + g(n) = 1$

Tags: induction

$$f(0) = 1\\                     
h(0) = 1\\                          
g(0) = 0\\
f(n + 1) = 1 − h(n)\\        
h(n + 1) = 1 − g(n + 1)\\              
 g(n + 1) = f(n)
$$

Prove using induction that $∀n ∈ \Bbb N: f(n) + g(n) = 1$

what i've done so far:

Base Case: $n=0$
$$
f(0) + g(0) = 1\\
1    +  0   = 1\\
1           = 1 $$

Step Case: 
$$
f(n+1) + g(n+1) = 1\\
1 - h(n) + f(n) = 1\\
1 - h(0) + f(0) = 1\\
1 -  1   +  1   = 1\\
1   = 1
$$
Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: You should use Latex to format your mathematics

Comment: You should prove from left hand side $f(n+1) + g(n+1)$ to right hand side $1$ in both the base and step cases.

Comment: how ? @peterwhy

Comment: Going off of what peterwhy said, you assume that the result holds for all integers up to $n$, and then show that it does for $n+1$; it looks like you assumed that it is holding for $n+1$. I will post an answer with some details

Comment: Instead of saying $f(0) + g(0) = 1$ on the first line without giving any reason, you should say like $$LHS = f(0) + g(0) = 1 + 0 = 1 = RHS$$And it is not clear where you have used your inductive hypothesis $$f(n) + g(n) = 1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have done the base case, let's look at the induction step. Assume that $f(k) + g(k) = 1$ for all $k\leq n$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
     f(n+1) + g(n+1) &= 1 - h(n) + f(n)\\
                     &= 1 - (1- g(n)) + f(n)\\
                     &= g(n) + f(n) \\
                     &= 1
\end{align*}
Because $f(n) + g(n) = 1$ by assumption.

Comment: how did you get 1 - (1-g(n)) + f(n) ?

Comment: and why 1 - h(n) + f(n) ?

Comment: Well we know that $h(n+1) = 1 - g(n+1)$ for all $n$, so $h(n) = 1 - g(n)$. Moreover we know that $f(n+1) = 1 - h(n)$ - these are coming from the list of properties that you wrote in your initial question.

Comment: okay now i get it, but i don't understand how u get 1-(1-g(n)) to g(n) ?

Comment: @clabbe $$1-(1-g(n)) = 1-1+g(n) = g(n)$$

Comment: This is just arithmetic: $1 - (1 - g(n)) = 1 - 1 + g(n)$ (just distribute the negative through the parentheses...)

Comment: yes yes got it now!

Comment: okay so is that enough for the problem? is it complete now?

Comment: Yes. Induction always works the same way: You first show the base step and then you show the induction step. You have then concluded that whatever it is that you are proving holds for all integers. Which we have just done here!

Comment: okay thank u so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I notice that you are pretty new here; you can vote for questions and answers that you like. And you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. This shows other people browsing SE that the question has been answered.